# How to add sources to Microsoft Word?

Tags: ms-word

I don't know if this s the right place for this, but I've been really struggling to get this done in word 2013, here's a photo of what I mean:
[Screenshot of a Word document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVGUF.jpg)

See how the `[5]` and the `[6]` are? I want to be able to do something like that. I've tried many things but nothing worked. And I don't really know how to google this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would've been better preserved in [Super User](https://superuser.com/), but here the solution:

The list on your screenshot are *end notes with square brackets*:

1. Insert **end notes**:

   - Go the the *References* tab in Word and do *Insert End Note*.
   - By default the end notes should be numbers, if they aren't click on the small symbol in right bottom of the tab.
     [image]
2. To get square brackets now, you have to do a **Seach and Replace operation**:

   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
   - Search for `^e` and replace it with `[^&]` (see on screenshot, it's German but should be no problem).

[image]

*Hint:* For foot nodes you can apply the same procedure, but instead of `^e`you have to take `^f`.

---

What you can also see, is a *table of figures*. How to create a table of figures:

1. You have to make **Captions**:

   - Go the the *References* tab in Word and do *Insert Caption*.
   - In the menue *"Caption"* which pops up you can select the label and further options.
2. You have to create a **Table of Figures**:

   - In the same word tab there is the button *"Insert Table of Figures"*.
   - In this menue you can choose the layout and further options.

---

*Version:* This guide works for any version of Microsoft Word, however the menues (how to find them) can differ in older versions (2003 and older).
The *Search&Replace Operation* works for every version.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work for me, the table of figures says that no TA fields were found.

Comment: Don't use the table of figures. Use the above solution with endnotes and `Ctrl+H`

Comment: Huh I don't know what you mean. I don't know how to create a table of figures and where exactly do I have to insert a caption?

Comment: Firstly I thought you want to create a table of figures according to what I have seen on the picture. But then I noticed you mean the endnotes in the very top of your screenshot.  So the second part of my post is irrelevant I think, but wasn't sure and I kept it. Just execute the part until my screenshot. If you are satisfied with the `endnotes`then, its ok and the second part becomes redundant.

Comment: Okay but do you see how my picture is? Above the hippo there is a number marked as [5] and [6]. And on the last slide there is a table of content that says [5] WIKIPEDIA LINK(Date). I want to know how to do this.

Comment: Yes this is what I have described. The date and the link are manually edited. Word doesn't know where you have adapted your sources from. the date is also manually set as the time of adaption.

Comment: Okay so I know how to setup the end notes but how exactly do I put them in a table of content like my picture has? So the table of content displays automatically like it is in my picture

Comment: The endnotes are automatically listed at the end of your document and a reference to where they are in your document is created. Thats why they are called *endnotes*.

Comment: Okay thanks haha but only one more thing how did you say you change the endnotes to a number? I mena what symbol do I have to click? Will rep you when I get home

Comment: I have added a screenshot, the screenshot is 2010 but its the same symbol in 2013, doesnt have 2013 here at the moment.